# Take random sample from each column by group in R

Tags: r, loops, random, sample, survey

I have a dataset with several thousand households and for each household the consumption of roughly 60 food items was recorded for one month of the year.

I want to generate annual food consumption for each household and food item for the remaining months of the year by repeatedly sampling (with replacement) from my data.

This is what my data looks like but with only 3 food items.

```
data <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow=120, ncol=5))
names(data) <- c("ID", "Month", "Apple", "Maize", "Bread")
data$ID <- 1:120
data$Month <- rep(1:12, each=10)
data$Apple <- data$Month + 2 * runif(12) - 1   # Consumption is seasonal but random
data$Maize <- data$Month + 2 * runif(12) - 1
data$Bread <- data$Month + 2 * runif(12) - 1

data
```

I want to group the data by month and then take a random sample from each column (food item) to have data for each household and item for every month of the year. The result should look like the data frame below.

```
data2 <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow=1440, ncol=5))
names(data2) <- c("ID", "Month", "Apple", "Maize", "Bread")
data2$ID <- rep(1:120, each=12)
data2$Month <- rep(1:12)

data2
```

Comment: (1) `data`-vs-`data1`, is that just a typo? (2) *"random sample from each column"*, just one sample from each month (and ID)? If so, why does `data2` have 1440 rows and `data1` only 120?

Comment: The original data frame from which I want to sample has each household just once and only has the food consumption info for one month of the year. Data2 has more rows as each household is listed 12 times for each month of the year. I want to sample from each month and item as many times as needed to complete Data2. I hope this makes more sense now?

Comment: I think so. You are ignoring `ID` when it comes to sampling, right? So really, we're using `data1$ID` (_perhaps fix your typo??_) only to determine the number of unique IDs to set in `data2`, otherwise it means nothing in the context of `data1`.

Comment: Yes, that's right, the IDs can be ignored. Fixed the typo. Thanks!